# What's the difference between is_page() and is_paged() in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I can't seem to understand `is_paged()` but I have used `is_page()` before. If possible please provide an sample page. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you had a look at the function reference?

- [`is_paged()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_paged)

  > This Conditional Tag checks if page being displayed is "paged". This is a boolean function, meaning it returns either TRUE or FALSE.
  >
  > Note: This refers to an archive or the main page being split up over several pages, this does not refer to a Post or Page whose content has been divided into pages using the  QuickTag.

  That means you get to know whether the current page is divided into several "subpages".
- [`is_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_page)

  > This Conditional Tag checks if [Pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages) are being displayed. This is a boolean function, meaning it returns either TRUE or FALSE.

Comment: what does "several pages" or "subpages" mean? Do you mean a page that contains excerpts of posts?

Comment: @adred: I'd say, e.g. the main page shows all the the posts right? But only a certain amount of e.g. posts are shown, e.g. 10. If you have 20 posts, the main page will consist of two subpages.

Answer (score 2):

The **$paged** global variable contains the page number of a listing of posts.

The **$page** global variable contains the page number of a single post that is paged.

Answer (score 1):

**is_paged():**

- this function does not take any argument, it is just returns true or false. Following example will make you clearly understand the theme.
- For example you have a blog. You have total 170 posts in your blog.
  When someone visits your blog's main page(it is also called index
  page), he/she sees 12 posts like this site ExcelDemy.com. To
  see other posts in your blog, people will click "older posts" or page number
  whatever you have set in the bottom portion of your index page. After
  one click on "Older Posts", you will be transferred to second page of
  the blog, see this link: and observe the URL [Second Page of the
  blog](http://www.exceldemy.com/page/2/).
- When you are in index page exceldemy.com, is_paged() function returns
  "False" as this page is not paged; When you are in second page [2](http://www.exceldemy.com/page/2/),
  is_paged() function returns "True" as you're in a paged page.